# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'truebomb' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I have some code where I am getting the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'truebomb' referenced before assignment.
```

In my code i have a variable `b`. Each time the code runs through, I add 1 to `b`.`b` is originally 1, and according to my code it will satisfy the equation.

```
import random

b=1

game=True

while game:

    if b==1:
        bomb=random.randint(1,9)

        if bomb== '8':
            truebomb=True

        if truebomb:
            game=False

    b=b+1

quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

If `bomb != 8`, `truebomb` is never set.

Regardless of the value of `bomb`, you're still asking your code to evaluate the truth of `truebomb`.  When `truthbomb` doesn't exist, you get an error.

If for some reason you don't want to set `truebomb` when `bomb != 8`, you can catch the exception, like this:

```
try:
    if truebomb:
        game = False

except UnboundLocalError:
    print('truebomb not set, continuing...')
    continue
```

Otherwise, 9.0's advice to set `truebomb = False` at the beginning is the best approach.

**Note that you don't actually need `truebomb` at all**.
You can just set `game = False` when `bomb == 8`.
Also, `bomb` is an integer, not a string, so compare to `8` not `'8'`:

```
bomb = random.randint(1,9)

if bomb == 8:
    game = False
```

Answer (score 0):

`truebomb` is not set to any value because `random.randint(1,9)` did not equal 8, and `truebomb` is only set to a value if `bomb` was 8. How to fix this problem: set `truebomb` to `False` before you start the game loop.

You have the same problem with your `bomb` variable. In the second iteration of the loop, an error will occur because `b!=1`. **Variables need to be assigned to values before they are used!!**